# How can I rewrite expression "using a raw OO notation" (from Guido's letter)

Tags: python, oop

While reading the documentation, I came across a link to Guido's [letter](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html):

Here's what he writes:

> Compare the easy with which we rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.

How can I rewrite this expression "using a raw OO notation"?

Comment: `x.multiply(a.add(b))`, here Guido compares operator overloading with method calling.

Comment: And the second expression would be `(x.multiply(a)).add(x.multiply(b))`